# eslint - new instance is considered un def?

Tags: eslint

**eslint rule**

```
{
   "no-undef": "error"
}
```

**index.html**

```
let instance = new plyr.setup({})
```

**error**

`plyr is not defined.`

How to tell ESlint `new plyr.setup({})` is not an undefined `var` but an a new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't understand the error. This mean that ESlint cannot find definition of `plyr` in current scope. Options to resolve this issue are:

1. Add `/* globals plyr */` at the top of the file to inform ESlint that this variable is defined outside current file and will be visible in this scope.
2. Use some kind of loader (Browserify and Webpack are most popular ones I believe).
3. Define `globals` in your ESlint configuration by adding following http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals